# How to plot the shortest path that visits multiple, unordered waypoints, given a start point?

Tags: routes, here-api

Using the HERE Maps API, is there a way to plot the quickest route given a start point and multiple, unordered stops?  For example: starting at waypoint0, waypoint1 is 100 miles due north, and waypoint2 is only 10 miles due north.  The route would be plotted from waypoint0 to waypoint2 to waypoint1.

Is it possible to achieve this with here-api?  If not, are there mapping services that offer this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Waypoint Sequence](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html). It will sort your initial list of waypoints into an optimized sequence. Then, you take that result to calculate the route joining all waypoints and to render it on a map.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [Tour Planning API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/2.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started/synchronous-request.html). With this API, you can solve problems like traveling salesman (finding the optimal order of visiting some destinations), and many other variations of the vehicle routing problem.

And then you can use this [example from the JS API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/map-with-route-from-a-to-b) to visualize the routes after you find the order to visit your waypoints.

Comment: No, this does not address my problem, but thank you for the prompt reply.  Here's another way to word the problem: how can one make here-api order a list of destinations in the most efficient single path?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, sorry I missed the part that you were looking to find the optimal order of visiting waypoints. Let me know if this helps :)